# Read barcode info from bitmap using ML kit

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-mlkit

I want to get some info from barcode using my camera.
It works when I use png image downloaded from site, but when I try to get it work with a photo I took, it outputs me the empty array. Seems like I need to make some preps with the image in order to make it work.
Here is my code:

```
fun getTheBarCode(bitmap: Bitmap) {
    val options = FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder()
            .setBarcodeFormats(
                    FirebaseVisionBarcode.FORMAT_AZTEC)
            .build()

    val detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionBarcodeDetector(options)
    val bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.barcode) //this is the place where I can load my downloaded barcode to make everything work!
    val newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 300, 500, false)
    val image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(newBitmap)

    photoImage.setImageBitmap(newBitmap)

    detector.detectInImage(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d("Success", "Success")
                //empty array here, when I take picture.
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d("Failed", it.message)
            }
}
```

This is how I get the image from the camera

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val photo = data.extras.get("data") as Bitmap

            getTheBarCode(photo)

        }
    }
```

**Edit:**

I've take a picture with my phone, scale it down to 1500x1000px and put it inside my app directory, then loaded it as a bitmap.
Still not working.

Comment: 1. Like another answer below, I suspect you get back a low quality thumbnail photo. 2. Depending on the type of barcode you are trying to parse, different resolutions are required. But 1280*960 can most of the time do. See public documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/barcode/FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector.html#detectInImage(com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImage).  Also, the barcode detection is on-device, so you don't need to resize the image before feeding it to the API.

Comment: @IsabellaChen please check the comment below. Large images also don't work.

Comment: But are you still scaling it to 300 * 500?  Could you remove the resizing logic? Also, try FirebaseVisionImage.fromFilePath. If still not working, share the image to me and I will take a look?

Comment: Hi did you resolve the issue? I am also facing the same problem, I am using the full quality photo following the https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics guide...not getting the barcode to work...

Answer (score 1):

The approach you're using will only give you back thumbnail of photo (as per https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics) ...that may not be sufficient for what you're trying to do.  That link also contains info on how to get access to full size photo.

Comment: Yes, that was a thumbnail. So I tried to take a picture, then save it as png in my project. I've loaded it as a bitmap and made a scan. Got empty array again. Seems like I definitely need to make some preps with the pic in order to make it work!